# Telerik Reporting Chart

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I am trying to build report using Telerik report designer and not able to identify if charts in below format are supported, if supported which chart type we have to use and which property will fill in color between low and high

candlestick , range chart only displays lines (2nd image)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the candlestick, it looks like a configuration issue. Please, check these things:

1. High, Low, Open, Close are not properly set
2. The data source fields that are used are not of numeric type (i.e. hold numerics as strings)

As for coloring the candlestick, check [`DataPointStyle`](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/report-items/graph/formatting-a-graph/series#formatting-data-points) property. there you can either set `BackgroundColor` directly, or use `DataPointConditionalFormatting` in order to add dynamic formatting based on the underlying data.
I am not sure what is the chart in the first picture, can you please shed some more light on its purpose?